# USRP1 with RFX2400: Loading the "unknown" daughterboard

Tags: gnuradio, usrp

I'm trying to utilize the outdated SDR USRP1 with a daughterboard RFX2400. But it does not provide any items.

So, I ran `uhd_usrp_probe`:

```
$ uhd_usrp_probe 
[INFO] [UHD] linux; GNU C++ version 5.4.0 20160609; Boost_105800;     UHD_3.11.0.git-94-g5964adcd
[INFO] [USRP1] Opening a USRP1 device...
[INFO] [USRP1] Using FPGA clock rate of 64.000000MHz...
[ERROR] [DBMGR] The daughterboard manager encountered a recoverable error in init.
Loading the "unknown" daughterboard implementations to continue.
The daughterboard cannot operate until this error is resolved.
LookupError: KeyError: key "0" not found in dict(i, N14adf4360_regs_t17prescaler_value_tE)
```

How should I resolve the error?